# cant calulate min/max/sum of column python

Tags: python

my code can calculate the min/max/sum of each row in the file alpha.txt provided, but it cannot calculate min/max/sum by column.... Any ideas on how to do it would be helpful, Thanks!

```
def load_data():

    usrnput = input("Enter a filename ")
    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open(usrnput, "+r")]


    row = len(my_list)
    column = len(my_list[0])

    if row != column:
        print("invalid")
    else:
        pass

    count = 0
    for row in(my_list):
        count = count + 1
        print(count, row)



    secondc = input("Enter a number ")
    if secondc == '2':
      minimum(my_list)
    elif secondc =='3':
        maximum(my_list)
    elif secondc =='4':
        sum1(my_list)

def minimum(my_list):
    pickaposition = input("Enter a row or column: ")
    if pickaposition == ('1'):
        print(min(my_list[0]))
    elif pickaposition == ('2'):
        print(min(my_list[1]))
    elif pickaposition == ('3'): 
        print(min(my_list[2]))
    elif pickaposition == ('4'):
        print(min(my_list[3]))
    elif pickaposition == ('5'):
        print(min(my_list[4]))


def maximum(my_list):
    pickaposition = input("Enter a row or column: ")
    if pickaposition == ('1'):
        print(max(my_list[0]))
    elif pickaposition == ('2'):
        print(max(my_list[1]))
    elif pickaposition == ('3'): 
        print(max(my_list[2]))
    elif pickaposition == ('4'):
        print(max(my_list[3]))
    elif pickaposition == ('5'):
        print(max(my_list[4]))

def sum1(my_list):
    pickaposition = input("Enter a row or column: ")
    if pickaposition == ('1'):
        print(sum(my_list[0]))
    elif pickaposition == ('2'):
        print(sum(my_list[1]))
    elif pickaposition == ('3'): 
        print(sum(my_list[2]))
    elif pickaposition == ('4'):
        print(sum(my_list[3]))
    elif pickaposition == ('5'):
        print(sum(my_list[4]))

def main():
    print("""1 - Open and load from a file
2 - Minimum
3 - Maximum 
4 - Sum 
5 - Delete
6 - Save
7 - Save as (specify new file name)
0 - Exit
""")
    pick = input("Enter a number ")

    if pick == "1":
        load_data()
    else:
        pass





main()
```

Also alpha.txt contains the data

```
5,4,2,3.2
1,.2,4.4,8
3,8,6.5,2
3,2,1,5.3
```

i really need to assign variable A-Z based on column, but i do not know how i would do that either.

here is a full sample run of my code to make it easier for you maybe.

```
1 - Open and load from a file
2 - Minimum
3 - Maximum 
4 - Sum 
5 - Delete
6 - Save
7 - Save as (specify new file name)
0 - Exit

Enter a number 1
Enter a filename alpha.txt
1 [5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.2]
2 [1.0, 0.2, 4.4, 8.0]
3 [3.0, 8.0, 6.5, 2.0]
4 [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.3]
Enter a number 3
Enter a row or column: 3
8.0
>>>
```

Comment: If it's really your code, you should be able to show the exact place which you don't know how to change. Otherwise it seems like it's the code of somebody else and you need to change it but don't want to spend your time.

Comment: you need to save the result of load_data in a 2D array(list of list). Then it will be easy to sum over the columns or over the rows.

Comment: it is indeed my code,ive posted here before on another account yesterday, but my login wont work for the account.

Comment: right on about the 2d array, that is what "    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open(usrnput, "+r")]" does. but since i cannot know for sure how many rows and columns there will be presented, i cannot hardcode the column like    

 columnA = [my_list[0][0],my_list[1][0],my_list[2][0],my_list[3][0]]
    columnB = [my_list[0][1],my_list[1][1],my_list[2][1],my_list[3][1]]
    columnC = [my_list[0][2],my_list[1][2],my_list[2][2],my_list[3][2]]
    columnD = [my_list[0][3],my_list[1][3],my_list[2][3],my_list[3][3]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question boils down to: Given a list of lists, which represents a grid/matrix, it is easy for you to extract a row but how do you extract a column?

Here's how you are doing a row:

```
>>> a = [[5, 4, 3, 3.2], [1, .2, 4.4, 8], [3, 8, 6.5, 2], [3, 2, 1, 5.3]]
>>> a[0]
[5, 4, 3, 3.2]
```

Here's a laborious way to do a column. Note that the first index changes but the second index doesn't. i.e. if we pick element 2 of each row we get a column!

```
>>> column_two = [a[0][2], a[1][2], a[2][2], a[3][2]]
>>> column_two
[3, 4.4, 6.5, 1]
```

You can make this easier with a list comprehension.

```
>>> [x[2] for x in a]
[3, 4.4, 6.5, 1]
>>>
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
column_two = []
for row in a:
    column_two.append(row[2])
```

After this you can re-use your existing functions and pass them the column you extract instead of the row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the list comprehension is definitely the way to go so once a gain thanks! what exactly though is column_two.append(row[2]) doing? append obviously adds something to the open list, but what is the 2 doing?

Comment: I really think you'll benefit from going through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). We are appending element 2 of each row to create the column. So the `[2]` is acting on the row only. You can think of this as on the previous line doing `element = row[2]` and then doing `column_two.append(element)`

Answer (score 2):

You can read in the file and store it as a lists of lists and then just sum the rows and columns. This summation can be done using [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

```
import itertools

with open('alpha.txt','rb') as f:
    values = [[float(word) for word in line.strip().split(',')] for line in f]

In [12]: values
Out[12]: 
[[5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.2],
 [1.0, 0.2, 4.4, 8.0],
 [3.0, 8.0, 6.5, 2.0],
 [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.3]]

col_sum = [sum(i) for i in itertools.izip(*values) ]
row_sum = [sum(i) for i in values]
```

Comment: what is the use of `*` in `itertools.izip(*values)`?

Comment: @samkhan13 It's the unpacking operator http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists. I need to get the variables before calling izip

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sum the columns by doing something like this:

```
def sumcolumn(my_list):
total = 0.0
pickaposition = input("Enter a column: ")
if pickaposition == ('1'):
    for x in row:
        total += my_list[x][0]
    print total
elif pickaposition == ('2'):
    for x in row:
        total += my_list[x][1]
    print total
elif pickaposition == ('3'): 
    for x in row:
        total += my_list[x][2]
    print total
elif pickaposition == ('4'):
    for x in row:
        total += my_list[x][3]
    print total
elif pickaposition == ('5'):
    for x in row:
        total += my_list[x][4]
    print total
```

Obviously this isn't very clean or pythonic, but hopefully it's simple enough to give you the idea, and you can adjust it to your specifications. I'd recommend and if block checking if it's a number between 1-5, and then using total += my_list[x][pickaposition-1] so you can save a lot of lines.

If you need any help with minimum/maximum, I can give examples for those too, but hopefully you'd be able to work out how to do it from this.

Answer (score 1):

if all of the elements within the table are of the same numeric type, consider using **numpy** array which will allow you to do numerical calculations very quickly.

**Example:**

```
import numpy

dataList = [[5, 4, 3, 3.2], [1, .2, 4.4, 8], [3, 8, 6.5, 2], [3, 2, 1, 5.3]] # this is a list of lists

dataArray = numpy.asarray(dataList)
```

Now let us look at our array:

```
dataArray
dataArray.dtype
```

which will produce the output:

```
array([[ 5. ,  4. ,  3. ,  3.2],
       [ 1. ,  0.2,  4.4,  8. ],
       [ 3. ,  8. ,  6.5,  2. ],
       [ 3. ,  2. ,  1. ,  5.3]])
dtype('float64')
```

python decided to define each element's type as `float64` to accomodate elements like 3.2, 0.2, 6.5, etc.

you can decide on the dtype of elements and assign it. (read the page about ndarray in the **references** section).

just remember that `axis=0` is the vertical direction and `axis=1` is the horizontal direction in numpy 2-dimensional arrays; you can actually have n-dimensional arrays and specify the axis accordingly.

now for the fast and efficient ways of calculating what you needed :

- sum

  ```
  columnSums = dataArray.sum(axis=0)
  columnSums
  ```

  which produces:

  ```
  array([ 12. ,  14.2,  14.9,  18.5])
  ```

  and

  ```
  rowSums = dataArray.sum(axis=1)
  rowSums
  ```

  which produces:

  ```
  array([ 15.2,  13.6,  19.5,  11.3])
  ```

  and

  ```
  overallSum = dataArray.sum()
  overallSum
  ```

  which is:

  ```
  59.599999999999994
  ```

similarly:

- min

  ```
  columnMins = dataArray.min(axis=0)
  rowMins = dataArray.min(axis=1)
  overallMin = dataArray.min()
  ```
- max

  ```
  columnMaximums = dataArray.max(axis=0)
  rowMaximums = dataArray.max(axis=1)
  overallMax = dataArray.max(dataArray)
  ```

you can even do things like:

```
thirdColSum = dataArray[:,2].sum()
lastRowSum = dataArray[-1].sum()
firstColAndTopTowRowsMin = dataArray[0:2,0].min()
bottomThreeRowsAndLastTwoCol = dataArray[-3:,-2:]
bottomThreeRowsAndLastTwoColMax = dataArray[-3:,-2:].max()
```

### References:

1. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html
2. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html
3. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.html
4. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html